# Python sequences (tuples)

Tags: python

Write a function square_odd_terms that accepts a tuple as an argument and returns a tuple with the odd terms in the tuple squared. Even terms will remain the same.

My attempt was:

```
def square_odd_termms(tpl):
    for i in (tpl):
        if i%2==0:
            return i
        else:
            return i**2
    return tuple(i)
```

Any help?

Attempt 2:

```
def square_odd_terms(tp1):
    for num in tp1:
        if num%2 != 0:
            return (num**2)
        else:
            return (num)
    return tuple(num)
```

Comment: just convert your list to a `tuple` ex `tuple([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: i'm supposed to write a general function, so i do not have numbers. any idea how to use tuple if i do not have physical numbers?

Comment: `l = [1,2,3,4]` then `tuple(l)`. If you can do with a constant list you can do with any list.

Comment: The best way to do this is with a comprehension.

Comment: You're trying to return the number, you need to either alter the tuple and replace it or whatever. `def func(tpl): tp1 = list(tpl); for item, i in enumerate(tp1): if item & 1 == 1: tp1[i]=item*item ; return tuple(tp1)`

Comment: @CharlesAddis As I said, use a comprehension.  Compare:  `def f(t): return tuple(v**2 if v&1 else v for v in t)`  Clearer, more compact, more efficient, more pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

Using generator comprehension if the number is odd square the number else just keep the number as is.

```
def square_odd_termms(tpl):
    return tuple((num**2 if num%2 else num for num in tpl))

>>> square_odd_termms((1,2,3,4,5,6))
(1, 2, 9, 4, 25, 6)
```

Answer for your attempt 2:You should not return the values in your "if" and "else" conditions which stops the function flow right there. Instead declare an empty array, assign these values for that array and return at the end

```
def square_odd_terms(tp1):
    result = []
    for num in tp1:
        if num%2 != 0:
            result.append(num**2)
        else:
            result.append(num)
    return tuple(result)
```

Comment: adding an explanation would be appreciated. Code-only answers are less useful (even if correct)

Comment: Documentation for comprehension: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: i also attempted something similar, but my code is more fragmented. can you help me see what is wrong? (edited in my qns)

Comment: You should not return the values in your "if" and "else" conditions which stops the function flow right there. Instead declare an empty array, assign these values for that array and return at the end,

Comment: note: `if num%2 != 0 ` => `if num%2 ` is shorter. Good answer

Answer (score 1):

You are close. However, your `return` statements in your first attempt will short-circuit the function.  A simple way to do this would be to iterate any iterable (tuple, list, etc.) and add new items to a new tuple.

Here is an example of [tuple concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459324/concatenating-tuple):

```
def square_odd_terms(iterable):
    result = tuple()
    for i in iterable:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            result += (i**2,)
        else:
            result += (i,)
    return result


numbers = (3, 6, 9, 10, 12)
square_odd_terms(numbers)
# (9, 6, 81, 10, 12)
```

The next level might be a [generator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator) that `yields` each element and is transformed to a tuple:

```
def square_odd_terms(iterable):
    """Yield squared odds and unchanged evens."""
    for i in iterable:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            yield i**2
        else:
            yield i


tuple(square_odd_terms(numbers))
# (9, 6, 81, 10, 12)
```

Next, you can mimic the latter with a [generator expression](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions) cast to `tuple()`:

```
def square_odd_terms(iterable):
    """Return a tuple of squared odds and unchanged evens."""
    return tuple(i**2 if i % 2!=0 else i for i in iterable)


square_odd_terms(numbers)
# (9, 6, 81, 10, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=lambda x: map(lambda i: i**2 if i%2 else i,x)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> t=(1,2,5,4)
>>> f=lambda x: tuple(map(lambda i: i**2 if i%2 else i,x))
>>> f(t)
(1, 2, 25, 4)
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifying your attempt 2:

def S_O(a):

```
l = []
for i in a:
    if i%2 != 0:
        l.append(i**2)
    else:
        l.append(i)
return tuple(l)
```

returns tuple

Execute your program twice. You will know what is wrong with default args.

```
>>> S_O((1,2,3))
(1, 2, 9)
>>> S_O((1,2,3,4))
(1, 2, 9, 1, 2, 9, 4)
```

Comment: may i know what does l.append means and does? Sorry new to python programming

Comment: l.append adds the element to the l

Comment: making the list a default argument is useless, confusing, and given how default args are created in python a sure recipe for unexpected results

Comment: Instead of making statement, It would be great, if you provide some sample code snippet which can prove your statement.